# Appropriate Action on Obsolete Answer

Tags: discussion, answers

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171328/131433) is an example of an answer which was offered in good faith when written and correct, as well. It is now, apparently, no longer correct. Does the OP deserve downvotes? Does the answer deserve deletion?

Comment: I would personally leave it at a comment, giving the OP a chance to update.